# Find the first point where a line touches a convex hull

Tags: matlab, line, convex-hull

First I have ploted a convex hull for given points using [convexHull](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.convexhull.html) Matlab function:

```
x = [4*rand(10,1)-2];
y = [rand(10,1)+5];
DT = delaunayTriangulation(x,y);
C = convexHull(DT);
plot(DT.Points(:,1),DT.Points(:,2),'.','MarkerSize',10)
hold on
plot(DT.Points(C,1),DT.Points(C,2),'r')
```

This convex hull is just an example, it can be any other convex hull. We assume that convex hull is inside parabola `y=x^2`.

Then I want to find first point on convex hull that touches line `y=[(a^2+1)/a]x-1`, when we start from `a=1` and it can go until `a=+\infty` if never touches convex hull (when convex hull is on LHS).

How that can be accomplished? My final goal is to find `a` on the figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each corner `(x_i, y_i)` of the polygon solve quadratic equation for `a_i`.

`y_i*a_i = (a_i^2 + 1)*x_i - 1`

You can obtain the equation by putting the point coordinates into the line equation. Next, discard solutions that are not relevant for You (`a<1`). Once this is done, sort solutions by `a`. If you also need the index of corresponding vertex, `sort` function in Matlab gives you indexing array as an additional output. You can then plot the line.

As a corner case, the line may hit two vertices. This is not a problem if you just need `a`. If you want the vertex id, just discard one arbitrarily, or use some additional rule.